# stop postgres processes from restarting - mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to run my rails projects but it keeps falling because it depends on postgres to be running. When I try to start postgres it keep saying its already running (or the port is taken). I checked activity monitor and there are ~6 postgres processes running, when I try to terminate/force-quit the processes, they just appear again...

not sure how to get around this issue.

actual error when running `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`:

> LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
>   HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
>   LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
>   HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
>   WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
>   FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets

and when I try to stop postgres with `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast`, I get this error:

> pg_ctl: PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid" does not exist
>   Is server running?

Comment: try killing the postgres process by process id

Comment: @adil tried that, a new process just replaces it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up starting from scratch:

- uninstall postgres through homebrew (`brew uninstall postgresql`)
- uninstall postgres though uninstaller (/Library/Postgresql/*version*/uninstall)
- delete postgres through file system (delete the folder: /Library/Postgresql/)

then just do a homebrew installation:

```
brew install postgresql
```

and start postgres manually.

Answer (score 2):

1:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast
```

2:

```
brew services stop postgresql
```